# Перемещение файлов с помощью bat скрипта

Tags: bat, cmd

Скрипт, который бы пытаться переместить содержимое одной папки в другую папку, пока первая папка не станет пустой. Говорю "пытаться", потому что в первой папке могут быть файлы, которые сейчас невозможно переместить во вторую папку, но когда-то возникнут условия, что этот возможно будет сделать. Нужен bat скрипт. Есть у кого какие идеи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идея такая

- перебрать все файлы во всех подкаталогах при помощи команды for
- Выполнить команду move
- Если %errorlevel% вернет ошибку, то что-то пошло не так.

Учесть, что в батнике переменная по for пишется с двумя %% и может называться только одной буквой.